# Show that $T(n) = 4 × T (n - 1) - T(n-2)$...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations

$T(n)$ is the number of spanning trees for the n-ladder.

Show that $T(n) = 4 × T (n - 1) - T(n-2)$.

-My teachers hint was to first show $T(n) = 3×T(n-1) + 2×T(n-2) + 2 × T(n-3) + ... + 2× T(2) + 3 × T(1) $

-I was unsure of what to do so I drew out the case for a 1-ladder, 2-ladder and 3-ladder.
[image]

-Even with these initial cases done, I am really unsure of where to go with this problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are still missing one: deleting the left edge and right bottom.

Comment: Yes i'm sorry I have that one, it was just cut off on the bottom of the picture.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69630/number-of-spanning-trees-in-a-ladder-graph