# Expected path length in a ladder-like graph if edges can be randomly removed.

Tags: probability, expected-value

Question from an old exam:

> The King of Squares sets out to patrol the City of Squares. The City of Squares is an infinite ladder, i.e., a graph $(V, E)$ where $V = \mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\}$ and the vertex $(x, y)$ is connected to $(x-1, y)$ for $x>0,(x+1, y)$ and $(x, 1-y)$. Unfortunately, due to the revolt, some parts of the streets are blocked. Each edge independently becomes blocked with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. The king leaves his palace at the point $(0,0)$. Let $X$ be the largest value of the coordinate $x$ that the King can reach without passing through the blocked streets.
> The king can look ahead, so he will choose the best route before he sets off.
> In the situation in the image below $X=5$.
>
> [image: Graph]
>
> (a) Find EX.
> (b) Find the probability that both points $(X, 0)$ and $(X, 1)$ are reachable.

My attempt at (a):
Let
$$
X_i = \begin{cases}
    i, & \text{if it's possible to reach $(i, 0)$ or $(i,1)$} \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Now we need to find the probability $p(i)$ that it is possible to reach the point $(i, 0)$ or $(i,1)$.

I have calculated that $p(i) = \frac{5}{8} p(i-1)$, where $p(1) = \frac{5}{8}$.
This is derived from the idea that the probability of going from coordinate$ (x, 0)$, to $(x+1, 0)$ or $(x+1, 1)$ is $\frac{5}{8}$.

Then $E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}E[X_i]=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i\cdot(\frac{5}{8})^i = \frac{40}{9}  \approx 4.44$.

Is this correct? How to do (b), because I don't know where to start?

Comment: Is $p$ set?  How do you get a numerical value for $p(1)$ if you don't know $p$?

Comment: One thing that makes it difficult is that it might matter how you advance.  For instance, if the lower node is blocked from forward or vertical motion, but the upper one allows forward motion, then you should make sure you arrive at the upper one, if possible.  Since you might have choices, that makes it tricky to argue that at each new level you restart the game.

Comment: I think you will need to consider the probability that you can get to the top (resp. bottom) node separately.

Comment: @lulu You are right. I edited the question, now the probability of edge being blocked is  $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: And you should explain whether or not the King can look ahead and plan the best journey.  Similarly, can the King go backwards?  That would have the same effect.  The problem is much simpler of course if the King can only judge the roads immediately in front of him, and can never go backwards.  But I expect you want to allow the King to choose the path.

Comment: @lulu King can look ahead. If there exists a path, he will find it.

Comment: Right,  so a simple recursion won't work.   Or, at least,  I don't see how it works.

Comment: @lulu I have no other idea how this can be done. I tried to find the number of good graphs of length $n$ (i.e., such that the king can reach coordinate $(n, 0)$ or $(n,1)$ by counting the bad ones:
$2^{3n}-0-(n+1)-(n-1+n-1+n(3n-2)+3n-2-1)-...$, where $2^{3n}$ is the number of all graphs, $0$ is the number of bad graphs with one edge removed, $(n+1)$ is the number of graphs with two edges removed, and so on, but this gets complicated very quickly.

Comment: Well, my suggestion was to separately track the probabilities that you can reach the top or the bottom one.  You can also recursively get the probability that you can reach both..they aren't independent, of course.  At a minimum, this will give an easy way to compute the result numerically.  After all, the probability that  you can reach the $20^{th}$ level or whatever is extremely small, so the approximation should be very accurate.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but to me the strategy dependence makes it hard.

Comment: Oh, one idea:  as soon as you have an intact vertical line, you really are restarting the game.  Maybe that's enough. Just consider the various things that can happen before you reach that intact vertical, if you ever do.

Comment: Can we adopt the following rules?  1- The king cannot go backward on any path he is on before. 2- The king selects one of the edges linked to its current place with equal probability. 3- After selecting an edge, the king can realize whether it is open or not.

Comment: @Amir The king can look ahead, so he will choose the best route before he sets off, so he won't be going backwards. If the king wants to cross a given edge then he has a probability of $1$ that he will succeed (the king chooses only those edges that exist).

Comment: If the king chooses the best route ahead, then the open edges (indexed by scenario $\omega$) need to be known at the time instant he decides, and thus the problem is nothing but solving an optimization problem to find the place with the maximum horizontal coordinate he can reach under scenario $\omega$, denoted by $x^*(\omega)$. Are you looking for the expectation of $x^*(\omega)$?

Comment: @Amir Yes, exactly. We have a random graph and we want to find the expected value of the furthest horizontal coordinate that can be reached by existing edges.

Comment: I could spare some time and added the required details to my answer. Let me know your feedback (@Alex Ravsky).

Comment: @Michał Do you need to find the pmf of $X$?

Comment: @Kroki No, I don't necessarily need to find a pmf. Also, thank you for the answer you wrote.

Comment: You are welcome. In that case feel free to ask if something is not clear in my answer.

Comment: I just updated my answer by adding a quick and elementary solution method. You may check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the **furthest horizontal coordinate** that the king can visit.

The pmf of $X$ is given by

$$\color{blue}{\mathbb P(X=n)=\frac{1}{2^{3n+4}}\left [\left(3 + \sqrt{5} \right)^{n+1} + \left(3 - \sqrt{5} \right)^{n+1}\right]}$$

for $n=0,1,2,\dots \, $.

This gives the expectation

$$\color{blue}{\mathbb E(X)=\frac{9}{5}}.$$

### How to obtain the probabilities

Here, we present **two methods**. The second is **easier**, but the first provides **deeper** analysis as it allows us to solve other problems imposing other conditions on a reachable point (e.g., analyzing part b in the OP for any fixed number of steps).

**First method:**

The probability is computed by counting subgraphs of a ladder graph with $n$ layers in which there is a path from (0,1) to **only** $(n,0)$, there is a path from (0,1) to **only** $(n,1)$, and there are paths from (0,1) to **both** $(n,0)$, $(n,1)$; denoted by $f_0(n)$, $f_1(n)$, and $f_{01}(n)$, respectively.

The following recurrences are used to determine $f_0(n)$, $f_1(n)$, and $f_{01}(n)$:

$$f_0(n)=2f_0(n-1)+f_{01}(n-1)$$
$$f_1(n)=2f_1(n-1)+f_{01}(n-1)$$
$$f_{01}(n)=4f_{01}(n-1)+2f_0(n-1)+2f_1(n-1)$$

with $f_0(0)=0, f_1(0)=1, f_{01}(0)=1$.

This gives

$$\color{blue}{\mathbb P(X=n)=\frac{f_0(n)+f_1(n)}{2^{3n+1}}\times \frac{1}{2}+\frac{f_{01}(n)}{2^{3n+1}}\times \frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{2^{3n+1}}\left [ \frac{1}{2}\left ( \frac{ (3 + \sqrt{5})^n (5 + \sqrt{5})- (3 - \sqrt{5})^n (-5 + \sqrt{5}) }{10} \right ) + \\
\frac{1}{4}\left( \left(3 + \sqrt{5} \right)^n  \left (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}} \right)+ \left (3 - \sqrt{5} \right )^n \left (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}} \right) \right ) \right]=\frac{1}{2^{3n+4}}\left [\left(3 + \sqrt{5} \right)^{n+1} + \left(3 - \sqrt{5} \right)^{n+1}\right]$$

**Second method:**

Alternatively, the probability can be obtained based on the number of subgraphs of a ladder graph with $n+1$ layers in which there is a path from (0,1) to one of $(n,0)$ or $(n,1)$, but there is no path to any of $(n+1,0)$ and $(n+1,1)$, which satisfies the following recurrence:

$$g(n)=6g(n-1)-4g(n-2)$$

with $g(0)=6, g(1)=28$. In this case, we have

$$\color{blue}{P(X=n)=\frac{g(n)}{2^{3(n+1)+1}}}$$

where

$$g(n)=\left(3 + \sqrt{5} \right)^{n+1} + \left(3 - \sqrt{5} \right)^{n+1}.$$

### How to derive the recurrences

Here I explain how I derived the first recurrence in the first method. The other recurrences in the first or second methods can be obtained similarly.

To see how the first recurrence $f_0(n)=2f_0(n-1)+f_{01}(n-1)$ is derived, see the figure below:

$\hskip 2.2 in$ [image]

This shows how different subgraphs of a ladder graph with $n$ layers in which there is a path from $(0,1)$ to **only** $(n,0)$ (referred to as *$0$ type* in the sequel) can be generated from  all subgraphs of a ladder graph with $n-1$ layers in which there is a path from $(0,1)$ to  $(n-1,0)$ or $(n-1,1)$.

1. You can see that we can generate $\color{blue}{\text{no subgraph}}$  of $0$ type from a subgraph of a ladder graph with $n-1$ layers in which there is a path from $(0,1)$ to  only $(n-1,1)$ (note that we can only change the lower, upper, and right edges in the $n$th cell).
2. Based on each subgraph of a ladder graph with $n-1$ layers in which there is a path from $(0,1)$ to  only $(n-1,0)$, we can construct $\color{blue}{\text{two subgraphs}}$ of $0$ type by adding either the lower edge or both lower and upper edges.
3. Based on each subgraph of a ladder graph with $n-1$ layers in which there are paths from $(0,1)$ to **both** $(n-1,0)$ and $(n-1,1)$, we can construct only $\color{blue}{\text{one subgraph}}$ of $0$ type by adding the lower edge. Note that adding both lower and upper edges results in a subgraph in which there are paths from $(0,1)$ to **both** $(n,0)$ and $(n,1)$, while here we want there is a path to **only** $(n,0)$.

The above observations together yield the following recurrence:

$$f_0(n)=2f_0(n-1)+f_{01}(n-1).$$

As I assumed the start point is $(0,1)$, as shown in the OP's figure, $f_0(0)=0$; note that this assumption does affect the final answer because of the symmetry.

### How to solve the recurrences

The single recurrence appearing in the **second method** can be solved easily.

Let me explain how to solve the system of recurrences appearing in the **first method**:

$$f_0(n)=2f_0(n-1)+f_{01}(n-1)$$
$$f_1(n)=2f_1(n-1)+f_{01}(n-1)$$
$$f_{01}(n)=4f_{01}(n-1)+2f_0(n-1)+2f_1(n-1)$$

with $f_0(0)=0, f_1(0)=1, f_{01}(0)=1$.

Let us define $s(n)=f_0(n)+f_1(n)$, and sum the first two recurrences to get

$$s(n)=2s(n-1)+2f_{01}(n-1).$$

and rewrite the third for $n$ and $n+1$ as follows:

$$f_{01}(n)=4f_{01}(n-1)+2s(n-1)$$
$$f_{01}(n+1)=4f_{01}(n)+2s(n).$$

Now multiply both sides of the above equations by $-1$ and $\frac{1}{2}$, respectively, sum the resulting equations, and use $s(n)-2s(n-1)=2f_{01}(n-1)$ to get the following second-order recurrence for $f_{01}$:

$$f_{01}(n+1)=6f_{01}(n)-4f_{01}(n)$$

with $f_{01}(0)=1$ and $f_{01}(1)=6$. This yields:

$$f_{01}(n)=\left(3 + \sqrt{5} \right)^n  \left (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}} \right)+ \left (3 - \sqrt{5} \right )^n \left (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}} \right).$$

This enables us to get $s(n)$ from $s(n)=2s(n-1)+2f_{01}(n-1)$ with $s(0)=0+1=1$, as follows:

$$s(n)=\frac{ (3 + \sqrt{5})^n (5 + \sqrt{5})- (3 - \sqrt{5})^n (-5 + \sqrt{5}) }{10}.$$

Note that from $f_0(n)=2f_0(n-1)+f_{01}(n-1)$ and $f_1(n)=2f_1(n-1)+f_{01}(n-1)$, both functions $f_0(n)$ and $f_0(n)$ can be found similarly, but  deriving $s(n)$ is enough for the first method.

Note that the probability requested in the **part b** of the OP is given by

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f_{01}(n)}{2^{3n+1}}\times \frac{1}{4}=\color{blue}{\frac{2}{5}}.$$

**The probabilities of other events** can be obtained based on $f_0(n)$, $f_1(n)$, $s(n)$, and $f_{01}(n).$

### Major update: $ \color{red}{\text{Quick and elementary solution method:}}$

Inspired from my first method, we can design a **quick and elementary** solution method that **directly computes** the expectation and the probability in part b, **without the need of** having the pmf or counting all the cases.

Let us define the following **three** related problems and **solve them simultaneously**:

> $\text{Problem}_0$: The king starts from $(0,0)$

> $\text{Problem}_1$: The king starts from $(0,1)$ (the same as in the OP)

> $\text{Problem}_{01}$: The king can start from any of $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$

Let $E_0$, $E_0$, and $E_{01}$ denote the expectation of **furthest horizontal coordinate** in the above problems, respectively. Then, by conditioning on the 8 combined situations of the lower, upper, and **left** edges of the **first** cell of the ladder graph, the following relations can be obtained:

$$E_0=\frac{3}{8}(1+E_0)+\frac{1}{8}(1+E_{1})+\frac{1}{8}(1+E_{01})$$
$$E_1=\frac{1}{8}(1+E_0)+\frac{3}{8}(1+E_{1})+\frac{1}{8}(1+E_{01})$$
$$E_{01}=\frac{2}{8}(1+E_0)+\frac{2}{8}(1+E_{1})+\frac{2}{8}(1+E_{01}).$$

> To better understand the method, consider 8 cases for the left, lower, and upper edges of the first cell. For **example**, consider the case that the left and upper edges are removed and the lower only exists (happen with probability of 1/8). By conditioning $E_0$ on this case (**one of the three cases** considered in the first term in the first row of the three dimensional system), the expected increment is 1 + $E_0$. For **another example**, consider the case that the lower edge is removed, and both upper and left exist (happen with probability of 1/8). By conditioning $E_0$ on this case (the **only** case considered in the second term in the first row of the three dimensional system), the expected increment is 1 + $E_1$. As the **third example**, consider the case that both left and lower edges are removed and only the upper exists (happen with probability of 1/8). By conditioning $E_0$ on this case, the increment is $0$.

Now by solving the above system, we **simultaneously** obtain all the three expectations: $$\color{blue}{E_0=E_1=\frac{9}{5}, E_{01}=\frac{11}{5}}.$$

The same can be done to get the probability in part b. Similarly, define $P_0$, $P_0$, and $P_{01}$ as the probability that the king needs to stop at some coordinate $i$ while he has paths to both $(i,0)$ and $(i,1)$. Then, by solving the following system:

$$P_0=\frac{1}{8}\times 1+\frac{3}{8}P_0+\frac{1}{8}P_{1}+\frac{1}{8}P_{01}$$
$$P_1=\frac{1}{8}\times 1+\frac{1}{8}P_0+\frac{3}{8}P_{1}+\frac{1}{8}P_{01}$$
$$P_{01}=\frac{2}{8}\times 1 +\frac{2}{8}P_0+\frac{2}{8}P_{1}+\frac{2}{8}P_{01},$$

we obtain the probability in part b for each of the three problems as follows:

$$\color{blue}{P_0=P_1=\frac{2}{5}, P_{01}=\frac{3}{5}}.$$

> For the problem in the OP, $E_0$ and $E_1$ or $P_0$ and $P_1$ are the same because of the symmetry. However, I kept both $E_0$ and $E_1$ so that the readers simply see how the method **can be adjusted for the asymmetric case** where the removal probabilities of the lower and upper edges are not equal.

Comment: I checked your arguments after the grey horizontal line up to the blue formula, and, as I understood them, they are correct (but King's starting vertex is $(0,0)$, not $(0,1)$). But I had to stop at the next formula, because its derivation was not provided.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks for your feedback! From the figure given in the OP, (0,1) is indicated as the start point, while in the question it is considered (0,0); anyway, it does not affect the result. I will add more details as I can spare some time.

Comment: How did you derive the recursive formula for $f_0$? I think you miscalculated something

Comment: The way you count $f_0$ does not seem correct to me.

Comment: @Kroki Now you can see **the step-by-step details** in the answer. I just added another image to clarify  the idea better. **Specifically**, could you let me know which part needs more clarification?

Comment: I still don't quite understand why you have $2$ instead of $1$ in $f_{01}(n)=4f_{01}(n-1)+2f_0(n-1)+2f_1(n-1)$. I can see one way to get to both $(n, 0)$ and $(n,1)$ if we only got to $(n-1, 0)$ before (and we can't visit $(n-1, 1)$). [See.](https://imgur.com/a/49NAgMF)

Comment: @Michał Please note that here we **do not count the possible paths**. Here, we count the subgraphs in which **there is a path** from the origin $(0,1)$ to only $(n,0)$, the subgraphs in which there is a path to only $(n,1)$, and the subgraphs in which there are paths to both $(n,0)$ and $(n,1)$. On your example, there is **only one path** from $(n-1,0)$ to both $(n, 0)$ and $(n, 1)$, but there are **two subgraphs** with such a path: one is obtained by adding the lower and right edges, and the other is obtained by adding the lower, right, and  **upper** edges (you see it is a bit tricky).

Comment: @Amir Of course. It makes sense now. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Amir I think your answer is good but I find it a little bit heavy and difficult to do in short time period like an exam.

Comment: @Kroki Thank you! To find **the pmf of $X$, not only the expectation**, I think we need such a solution.

Comment: No you can find the pmf by using the **MGF** of $X$ which can be computed easily.

Comment: @Amir can you explain your last method I am not I get it right. What are cases of transitions?

Comment: Good catch. It is similar to my method I was looking at the edge on the right instead of the left. By the way you don't need $E_1$ because it is always $=E_0$

Comment: @Kroki It's great that you like it. The idea of using conditional expectation is similar to yours. The newly added idea that makes the method simple is to the define three parallel problems and simultaneously solve them. Yes exactly, but I kept both $E_0$ and $E_1$ so that readers simply see how the method can be adjusted for the case where the removal probabilities of the lower and upper edges are not equal.

Comment: All the answers are great, but I like this one the best because it was the easiest for me to understand. Thank you all again!

Answer (score 4):

For each nonegative integer $x$ and each $Y\subset\{0,1\}$ let the event $R_{x,Y}$ be:
for each $y\in \{0,1\}$ we have $y\in Y$ iff there exists an abscissa-nondecreasing path from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$. Then $p(R_{0,\varnothing})=0$, $p(R_{0,\{0\}})=\frac 12$, $p(R_{0,\{1\}})=0$, and $p(R_{0,\{0,1\}})=\frac 12$. Moreover, it is easy to see that for each natural $x\ge 0$ we have:
$$p(R_{x+1,\varnothing})=p(R_{x,\varnothing})+\frac 12 p(R_{x,\{0\}})+\frac 12 p(R_{x,\{1\}})+ \frac 14 p(R_{x,\{0,1\}}),$$
$$p(R_{x+1,\{0\}})=0p(R_{x,\varnothing})+\frac 14 p(R_{x,\{0\}})+0 p(R_{x,\{1\}})+ \frac 18 p(R_{x,\{0,1\}}),$$
$$p(R_{x+1,\{1\}})=0p(R_{x,\varnothing})+0p(R_{x,\{0\}})+\frac 14 p(R_{x,\{1\}})+ \frac 18 p(R_{x,\{0,1\}}),$$
$$p(R_{x+1,\{0,1\}})=0p(R_{x,\varnothing})+\frac 14 p(R_{x,\{0\}})+\frac 14 p(R_{x,\{1\}})+ \frac 12 p(R_{x,\{0,1\}}).$$

Put $p_x=(p(R_{0,\varnothing}),p(R_{x,\{0\}}),p(R_{x,\{1\}}),p(R_{x,\{0,1\}}))^t.$ Then $p_0=\left(0,\frac 12,0,\frac 12\right)^t$, and for each nonnegative integer $x$ we have $p_{x+1}=Ap_x$, where
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac 12 & \frac 12 & \frac 14 \\
0 & \frac 14 & 0 & \frac 18 \\
0 & 0 & \frac 14 & \frac 18 \\
0 & \frac 14 & \frac 14 & \frac 12
\end{pmatrix}.$$

That is, $p_x=A^xp_0$. Let
$$T=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -3-\sqrt{5} & 3-\sqrt{5} \\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1+\sqrt{5} & -1+\sqrt{5}
\end{pmatrix}$$
be the matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of the matrix $A$. Then [$D=T^{-1}AT=
\operatorname{diag}\left(1,\frac 14,\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{8},\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{8} \right)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B%7B%7B1%2C0%2C-3-Sqrt%5B5%5D%2C3-Sqrt%5B5%5D%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C1%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C1%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2BSqrt%5B5%5D%2C-1%2BSqrt%5B5%5D%7D%7D%2C-1%5D%7B%7B1%2CDivide%5B1%2C2%5D%2CDivide%5B1%2C2%5D%2CDivide%5B1%2C4%5D%7D%2C%7B0%2CDivide%5B1%2C4%5D%2C0%2CDivide%5B1%2C8%5D%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2CDivide%5B1%2C4%5D%2CDivide%5B1%2C8%5D%7D%2C%7B0%2CDivide%5B1%2C4%5D%2CDivide%5B1%2C4%5D%2CDivide%5B1%2C2%5D%7D%7D%7B%7B1%2C0%2C-3-Sqrt%5B5%5D%2C3-Sqrt%5B5%5D%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C1%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C1%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2BSqrt%5B5%5D%2C-1%2BSqrt%5B5%5D%7D%7D%3D)
is the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$. Thus $p_x=TD^xT^{-1}p_0$.

(b) The required event happens iff $R_{X,\{0,1\}}$ and both horizontal edges from the $X$-th column of the graph to the $X+1$ column are blocked. That is, the required probability is $\frac 14 p(R_{X,\{0,1\}})$,
which is $\frac 14$ multiplied by the last component of the vector $TD^XT^{-1}p_0$, that is
$$\frac 1{10\cdot 8^{X+1}}\left(\left(5+3\sqrt{5}\right)\cdot \left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)^X+
\left(5-3\sqrt{5}\right)\cdot\left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)^X\right).$$

(a) For each nonegative integer $x$ we have $X\ge x$ iff not $R_{x,\varnothing}$. It follows
$$EX=\sum_{x=1}^\infty xP(X=x)=\sum_{x=1}^\infty x(P(X\ge x)-P(X\ge x+1))=$$
$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty x(p(R_{x+1,\varnothing}))-p(R_{x,\varnothing}))=\lim_{z\to\infty} z p(R_{z+1,\varnothing})-\sum_{x=1}^z p(R_{x,\varnothing}).$$

The expression under the limit is the first component of the vector $(zA^{z+1}-\sum_{x=1}^z A^x)p_0$,
that is of the vector $T(zD^{z+1}-\sum_{x=1}^z D^x)T^{-1}p_0$. Let $\xi$ be any real number such that $|\xi|<1$. Let the positive integer $z$ tends to the infinity. We have $z\xi^{z+1}-\sum_{x=1}^z \xi^x=
z\xi^{z+1}-\xi\frac{1-\xi^z}{1-\xi}$, and the latter expression tends to $\frac{-\xi}{1-\xi}$.
Therefore the matrix $zD^{z+1}-\sum_{x=1}^z D^x$ converges to a diagonal matrix $$D'=\operatorname{diag}\left(1,-\frac 13,\frac{-5-2\sqrt{5}}{5},\frac{-10-\sqrt{5}}{10}\right).$$
Then the first component of the vector $TD'T^{-1}p_0$ equals $$\frac {46+5\sqrt{5}}{20}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I need to brush up on my linear algebra a bit before I fully understand this ;)

Comment: @Michał I completed my answer. I hope that I did not make arithmetic errors in my calculations.

Comment: Alex, is the expectation you found $$\frac {46+5\sqrt{5}}{20}?$$ I obtained $\frac{9}{5}$. Could you check my result?  (@Michał)

Comment: @Amir I am going to do this later. But before this you can calculate $p_X(n)$ for small $n$ and compare these values with your and my formulae. This can be helpful to rule out one of expectations we calculated, because they differ in a few times.

Comment: You may see that the sum of the values of your **pmf is less than 1**:

$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac 1{10\cdot 8^{x+1}}\left(\left(5+3\sqrt{5}\right)\cdot \left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)^x+
\left(5-3\sqrt{5}\right)\cdot\left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)^x\right)=0.4.$$

Comment: On to your statement:

$ $
*The required event happens iff $R_{X,\{0,1\}}$ and both horizontal edges from the $X$-th column of the graph to the $X+1$ column are blocked. 
That is, the required probability is $\color{blue}{\frac 14} p(R_{X,\{0,1\}})$* 

$ $
**A point that may help** is that the blocking probability **is not always** $\frac{1}{4}$. In some cases, it is $\frac{1}{2}$, depending on the situation of the graph (see my first method).

Comment: @Amir The sum of the values of my pmf can be less than $1$, because there can be he cases when (b) is not satisfied. Both horizontal edges have to be blocked because $R_{x,\{0,1\}}$ implies that both vertices in the $X$th column are accessible (via an abscissa-nondecreasing path), so the multiplier is always $\frac 14$.

Comment: I think the matrix $T$ is not correct when I use a computer I find another matrix $T$.

Comment: @Kroki There can be several matrices $T$ such that $T^{-1}AT$ is diagonal. For instance, I guess, we can any matrix whose columns are any eigenvectors of the matrix $A$, corresponding to its distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes I know but I don't think the $T$ you have is one of them.

Comment: @Kroki I calculated the equality $D=T^{-1}AT$ via Mathcad. Do you disagree with the equality?

Comment: I tried with sagemath and did not give the equality

Comment: @Kroki Wolfram Alpha agrees with Mathcad. I added the link to the answer

Answer (score 1):

#### Notations:

- $U_n$ the event that the upper horizontal edge is not blocked at $n$.
- $L_n$ the event that the lower vertical edge is not blocked at $n$.
- $V_n$ the event that the vertical edge is not blocked at $n$.
- $N = \inf\left\{ n \in \mathbb N_{\ge 1}\, : \, L_n \cap U_n \cap V_n^c\; \text{is false}\right\}$, $N$ follows a geometric distribution $\mathcal G\left(p = \frac78\right)$

#### Question a:

##### Idea:

The idea is to establish a system of equations such that $\mathbb E\left[X\mid V_0\right]$ and $\mathbb E\left[X \mid V_0^c\right]$ are solutions of the system.

##### Recursion:

- In the case of $V_0^c$, \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Event} &  \textbf{Probability} & \textbf{Expectation}\\
  \hline
  L_1^c & \frac12 & 0\\
  \hline
  L_1 \cap V_1^c & \frac14 & 1 + \mathbb E\left[X \mid V_0^c\right]\\
  \hline
  L_1 \cap V_1 & \frac14 & 1 + \mathbb E\left[X \mid V_0\right]\\
  \hline
  \end{array}
- In the case of $V_0$, \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Event} &  \textbf{Probability} & \mathbb E\left[X\mid N\right]\\
  \hline
  L_N\cap U_N\cap V_N^c & 0 & \\
  \hline
  L_N^c\cap U_N^c & \frac27 & N - 1\\
  \hline
  L_N \cap U_N^c \cap V_N^c & \frac17 & N + \mathbb E\left[X \mid V_0^c\right]\\
  \hline
  L_N^c \cap U_N \cap V_N^c & \frac17 & N + \mathbb E\left[X \mid V_0^c\right]\\
  \hline
  \left(L_N \cup U_N\right) \cap V_N & \frac37 & N + \mathbb E\left[X \mid V_0\right]\\
  \hline
  \end{array}

##### Formulas:

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[X \mid V_0^c\right] &= \frac14 \left(1 + \mathbb E\left[X\mid V_0\right]\right) + \frac14 \left(1 + \mathbb E\left[X \mid V_0^{c}\right]\right)\\
&= \frac12 + \frac14 \mathbb E\left[X \mid V_0\right] + \frac14 \mathbb E\left[X \mid V_0^c\right]
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[X\mid V_0\right] &= \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[X \mid N\right] \mid V_0\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[N\right] - \frac27 + \frac27 \mathbb E\left[X\mid V_0^c\right] + \frac37\mathbb E\left[X\mid V_0\right]\\
&= \frac87 - \frac27 + \frac27 \mathbb E\left[X\mid V_0^c\right] + \frac37\mathbb E\left[X\mid V_0\right]\\
&= \frac67 + \frac27 \mathbb E\left[X\mid V_0^c\right] + \frac37\mathbb E\left[X\mid V_0\right]
\end{align}

You can solve this system and evaluate: $$\mathbb E\left[X\right] = \frac12\left(\mathbb E\left[X\mid V_0\right] + \mathbb E\left[X\mid V_0^c\right]\right) = \frac95.$$

---

#### Question b:

A similar way can be done for the probability of the second question. Indeed if $A$ is the event that the $0$ and $1$ are reachable at $X$ you will have:

##### Recursion

- In the case of $V_0^c$, \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Event} &  \textbf{Probability} & \mathbb P\left[A\right]\\
  \hline
  L_1^c & \frac12 & 0\\
  \hline
  L_1 \cap V_1^c & \frac14 & \mathbb P\left[A \mid V_0^c\right]\\
  \hline
  L_1 \cap V_1 & \frac14 & \mathbb P\left[A \mid V_0\right]\\
  \hline
  \end{array}
- In the case of $V_0$, \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Event} &  \textbf{Probability} & \mathbb P\left[A\mid N\right]\\
  \hline
  L_N\cap U_N\cap V_N^c & 0 & \\
  \hline
  L_N^c\cap U_N^c & \frac27 & 1\\
  \hline
  L_N \cap U_N^c \cap V_N^c & \frac17 & \mathbb P\left[A \mid V_0^c\right]\\
  \hline
  L_N^c \cap U_N \cap V_N^c & \frac17 & \mathbb P\left[A \mid V_0^c\right]\\
  \hline
  \left(L_N \cup U_N\right) \cap V_N & \frac37 & \mathbb P\left[A \mid V_0\right]\\
  \hline
  \end{array}

##### Formulas:

\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left[A \mid V^c\right] &= \frac14 \mathbb P\left[A \mid V\right] + \frac14 \mathbb P\left[A\mid V^c\right]
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left[A \mid V_0\right] &= \frac27 + \frac27 \mathbb P\left[A\mid V_0^c\right] + \frac37\mathbb P\left[A\mid V_0\right] 
\end{align}

You can solve this system and finally evaluate the following:

$$\mathbb P\left[A\right] = \frac12 \left(\mathbb P\left[A\mid V\right] + \mathbb P\left[A\mid V^c\right]\right) = \frac25.$$

---

#### Question c:

If you want to find the pmf of $X$, do the same idea to $\mathbb E\left[t^X\right]$. Let $f(t) = \mathbb E\left[t^N\right]$.

##### Recursion

- In the case of $V_0^c$, \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Event} &  \textbf{Probability} & \mathbb E\left[t^X\right]\\
  \hline
  L_1^c & \frac12 & 1\\
  \hline
  L_1 \cap V_1^c & \frac14 & \mathbb E\left[t^{1+X} \mid V_0^c\right]\\
  \hline
  L_1 \cap V_1 & \frac14 & \mathbb E\left[t^{1+X} \mid V_0\right]\\
  \hline
  \end{array}
- In the case of $V_0$, \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Event} &  \textbf{Probability} & \mathbb E\left[t^X\mid N\right]\\
  \hline
  L_N\cap U_N\cap V_N^c & 0 & \\
  \hline
  L_N^c\cap U_N^c & \frac27 & t^{N-1}\\
  \hline
  L_N \cap U_N^c \cap V_N^c & \frac17 & t^N\mathbb E\left[t^{X} \mid V_0^c\right]\\
  \hline
  L_N^c \cap U_N \cap V_N^c & \frac17 & t^N\mathbb E\left[t^X \mid V_0^c\right]\\
  \hline
  \left(L_N \cup U_N\right) \cap V_N & \frac37 & t^N\mathbb E\left[t^X \mid V_0\right]\\
  \hline
  \end{array}

##### Formulas:

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[t^X\mid V_0^c\right] &= \frac12 + \frac14 t\left(\mathbb E\left[t^X\mid V_0^c\right] + \mathbb E\left[t^X\mid V_0\right]\right)
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[t^X\mid V\right]
&= f(t) \left(\frac2{7t} + \frac27 \mathbb E\left[t^X\mid V_0^c\right] + \frac37 \mathbb E\left[t^X\mid V_0\right]\right)
\end{align}

Now solve the system and evaluate:

\begin{align}
g(t) &= \mathbb E\left[t^X\right] = \frac12 \left(\mathbb E\left[t^X\mid V^c\right] + \mathbb E\left[t^X\mid V\right]\right)\\ &= \frac{6-t}{t^2 - 12t + 16}\\
&= \frac12 \left(\frac{1}{6 + 2\sqrt{5} - t} + \frac{1}{6 - 2\sqrt{5} - t}\right)\\
&= \frac12 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac1{6+2\sqrt{5}}\right)^{n+1} + \left(\frac1{6-2\sqrt{5}}\right)^{n+1}\right)t^n
\end{align}

Where the last two steps use the partial fraction decomposition and the fact that $\frac1{a-t} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{a^{n+1}}t^n$ for $t$ near $0$.

So $$\mathbb P\left[X = n\right]= \frac12 \left(\left(\frac1{6+2\sqrt{5}}\right)^{n+1} + \left(\frac1{6-2\sqrt{5}}\right)^{n+1}\right)$$

Comment: You derived the expectation only. How can you find **the pmf of** $X$?

Comment: You can use the **MGF** of $X$.

Comment: Yes, but I think it is a bit difficult. Anyway, I am happy that after some days that you were thinking my answer was **incorrect**, you also got the same value of expectation $\frac{9}{5}$. Thanks for your confirmation!

Comment: I don't think it is harder than yours but the idea is easier to catch.

Comment: I think working with my **second method** is not difficult to get the pmf because you only need to derive and solve $g(n)=6g(n-1)-4g(n-2)$. I provided my **first method**, which has more details and may look heavy, to have a deeper analysis of the problem.

Comment: If you want to compute the expectation you don't need to count. You only need to know a little bit about geometric distribution and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Define a Markov chain as follows:

- There are $4$ states $11,10,01,00$. We are in state $10$ at time $i$ if $(i,0)$ is reachable *using only roads to the left of $i$* – i.e. left-only reachable – but $(i,1)$ is not, in state $11$ if both $(i,0)$ and $(i,1)$ are left-only reachable and similarly for the other two states.
- At $i=0$ we are in $11$ or $10$ with equal probability, corresponding to whether or not the leftmost rung of the ladder is blocked.
- Three edges are needed to compute the transition probabilities – the next rung and two side edges – and the transition matrix is
  $$P=\begin{bmatrix}
  1/2&1/4&1/4&0\\1/8&1/4&0&0\\1/8&0&1/4&0\\1/4&1/2&1/2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p_{11}\\p_{10}\\p_{01}\\p_{00}\end{bmatrix}$$
  Let the upper-left $3×3$ submatrix be $Q$; $Q^iv=Q^i(1/2,1/2,0)^T$ furnishes the probabilities of being in some transient (non-absorbing) state at time $i$. The remaining nonzero matrix $b=(1/4,1/2,1/2)^T$ gives the absorbing probabilities for each state.
- For this problem we need not consider reachable but not left-only reachable points – such a point implies $X$ is larger than where the king is currently at. So our chain really is a Markov chain, with $00$ an absorbing state.

The fundamental matrix is
$$N=(I-Q)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{12}5&\frac45&\frac45\\\frac25&\frac{22}{15}&\frac2{15}\\\frac25&\frac2{15}&\frac{22}{15}\end{bmatrix}$$
and when left-multiplied by the all-ones vector produces the expected number of steps before absorbing if we start at a specific state, i.e. $E(X)+1$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{16}5_{11}&\frac{12}5_{10}&\frac{12}5_{01}\end{bmatrix}$$
Taking the average of the first two components and subtracting $1$ gives the answer to (a) as $\frac95$.

$Q^iv\circ b$, where $\circ$ is the elementwise product, gives the probabilities of $X=i$ with given final transient state. The sum of this over all $i$
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty Q^iv\circ b=\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty Q^i\right)v\circ b=(I-Q)^{-1}v\circ b=Nv\circ b=\begin{bmatrix}\frac25_{11}\\\frac7{15}_{10}\\\frac2{15}_{01}\end{bmatrix}$$
is the distribution of states at $X=i$ – their sum is $1$ as they should be. Finally the answer to (b) is $\frac25$.